# How do i disable iastor.sys

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, bsod

I need to disable `iastor.sys` as I think this is the reason why my computer to keeps blue screening.

I need to be able to do this from within safe mode as I cannot log in to computer normally.

Comment: Check your HDD.  It could be failing.

Comment: Update your Intel Drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, it's required to read from your hard drive. It's the Intel Storage Driver...

Comment: o i thought it had somthing to do with system restore